# edit apk decompiled code

Tags: android, edit

i **decompiled** a app with **apktool** and **dex2jar**...i have the java code and xml code now...
Actually this android app is a sample of **get follower for instagram** which the app   connected with a web server and in app when we follow one guy , the app give us 1 coin...Anyway i want change somethings in this app codes which while i follow a guy Instead 1 coin give me 2 or bigger number coin...

Is there a way to do this?

thanks

Comment: sorry for bad english...

Answer (score 0):

Nobody will answer this questions, since your probably did not have the permission to obtain the source Code...